# Weighted variance

Tags: statistics

Let's say I have 60% of some data where the mean is 6 and the other 40% has a mean of 4.
Then together the mean is calculated by taking 0.6*6 + 0.4*4 = 5.2, right?

I know you can't do the same with variance though. So let's say I was given the variances of those two parts of data, how would I go about calculating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variance works the same, only you have to work with second moment.

Second moment is the mean of $X^2$. Since you do not have any numbers I will use variables, $V_1$ and $V_2$

For 60% of the sample $E[X^2] = 6^2+V_1=36+V_1$

For 40% of the sample $E[X^2] = 4^2+V_2 = 16+V_2$

So for the entire sample
$$
E[X] = 0.6\cdot 6 + 0.4 \cdot 4 = 5.2 \\
E[X^2] = 0.6 (36+V_1) + 0.4 ( 16+V_2) = 28 + 0.6 V_1 + 0.4 V_1 
$$
So the variance for the whole population 
$$
28 + 0.6 V_1 + 0.4 V_2 - 5.2^2  = 0.96 + 0.6 V_1 + 0.4 V_2
$$